# Band-pass RLC Filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

By calculating one of my RLC filter circuit values, I got L=3.8*exp(-10), C=6.6*exp(-11) and R=8.3*exp(5).
My question is:
1. Are these values of R, L and C practically realizable?
2. Is it normal that we get these types of values, let suppose for L=3.8*exp(-10)?

Comment: How many tens of GHz is your mid-frequency?

Comment: Which power? Which frequency range?

Answer (score 0):

R and C are realizable , L is not.  It looks like you plugged some values into a cookbook formula and are trying for a 1 GHz corner or center frequency. Can you provide more details?.

Comment: As crazy as it may sound, Coilcraft manufactures 0.5 nH 0201 chip inductors with SRF approx 24 GHz. Close enough. http://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/0201ds.pdf

Comment: Standard values \$\pm 10 ~\%\$ or \$\pm 20 ~\%\$ are from the [E24 or E12 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-series_of_preferred_numbers) of values.